# Cookie assigned on aspx page diplays wrong value in codebehind file

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have a  modal popup. Whenever I click on that popup it return a value which I need to store in a cookie in aspx in java script function. After completing that java script function compiler goes to other user control and last it comes to a page there  i need  to(in .cs page) retrieve the cookie value which i have assigned in aspx page. it is giving correct value in first click(in popup).but from second on-words it is showing the previous clicked value.ex : popup list values are 1,2,3,4:first click  :1 second click : 1
third click : 2 like its giving. Below is the code which i have written.
cookies creation in aspx in user control :

```
 function createCookie(cookievalue)
 {
      var myDate = new Date();
      myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
      document.cookie = "OPEntityServiceName =" + cookievalue + ";
      expires=" + myDate + ";path=/";
 }
```

**Cookies reading :** after the above function is executed it will be redirected to some other page ,in that page

```
 :hdnServiceName.Value = Request.Cookies["OPEntityServiceName"].Value.ToString();
```